# Rxjs 6 flatten observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I need your advice on how to convert the Rxjs 5 to Rxjs 6.

My code is below and I am not too sure why it did not work.

Rxjs 5

```
Observable.from([{amount:5},{amount:10}])
.flatMap(_ => depositService.deposit(depositAmount))
.toArray()
.subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result.length);
})
```

Rxjs 6

```
import { Observable, from, } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError, mergeMap} from 'rxjs/operators';
...

const source = from([{amount:5},{amount:10}]);
source
.pipe(mergeMap(_ => depositService.deposit(_.amount).toArray())
.subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result.length);
})
```

I got the error

You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

Comment: `toArray` is an operator, so it needs to be passed to `pipe` - not chained off the call to `deposit`: `pipe(mergeMap(_ => depositService.deposit(_.amount)), toArray())`

Comment: No it did not work

Comment: Some elaboration on "did not work" will be required if you desire further assistance.

Answer (score 7):

I think toArray is an operator and should be passed in in the pipe.

```
import { Observable, from, } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError, mergeMap, toArray} from 'rxjs/operators';
...

const source = from([{amount:5},{amount:10}]);
source
.pipe(
    mergeMap(_ => depositService.deposit(_.amount)),
    toArray()
)
.subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result.length);
})
```

Comment: I was able to do it, the toArray() operation should be after the mergeMap